# On click change url to random vars

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a link, when user clicks it to change URL randomly to one of the vars.

```
$(".link").click(function(){

    var safeLangs = ['en','al','de','fr','gr'];
    var rand = function() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
    };
    var randomLangFunction = function() {
        var randomLang = safeLangs[rand()];
        return randomLang;
    };

   url = "?lang=" + randomLang();
   window.location = url;
})
```

Problem is fixed by, thanks.
[By Scott Marcus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40915953/4700604)

Comment: Do you mean `window.location += url;` perhaps? Not sure what your problem is.

Comment: Url should change randomly to something.
ex. localhost/?lang=al lets say, but if its clicked again should be changed into localhost/?lang=en

Comment: Should only the displayed URL change or do you actually want to go to another page?

Comment: @ErblinDerguti Don't post the correct code in your question, just mark the correct answer as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your code, you incorrectly call your function: `randomLang();` when it is really: `randomLangFunction()`. I also removed your `rand` function and incorporated it into the other.

```js
$(".link").click(function(){

    var safeLangs = ['en','al','de','fr','gr'];
  
    var randomLangFunction = function() {
        // No need to make a separate function for the random since
        // this function is part of that process.  Also, don't hard 
        // code "6" as the random multiplier as that will need to 
        // change if you add more languages. Just get the length
        // of the languages array:
        return safeLangs[Math.floor(Math.random()*safeLangs.length)];
    };

   url = "?lang=" + randomLangFunction();
   console.log(url);

   // Commented only for example to work:
   // window.location = url;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link" href="#">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother :)
It worked.

P.s. So i was almost close lol.

Comment: @ErblinDerguti No problem. Don't forget to mark as answer. ;)